# Folding - open all, close one

Tags: folding

There are a few commands to use folding (amongst all):

```
za      When on a closed fold: open it. [...]
        When on an open fold: close it [...]

zA      When on a closed fold: open it recursively.
        When on an open fold: close it recursively [...]
```

However my "ideal" keystroke (which would be most commonly used), would be:

```
        When on a closed fold: open it recursively.
        When on an open fold: close it (only one, like in `za` command)
```

How to define such a mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>z foldclosed('.') != -1 ? 'zO' : 'zc'
```

See `:h :map-<expr>`.  On a fold, use `zO` to open it recursively, otherwise use `zc` to close one fold.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a mapping, just use the `zc/zC` and `zo/zO` commands.

`zc` will close the fold at the current line, and `zC` will close all of the folds at the  current line, while `zo` and `zO` will open one level and all levels of folds at the current line,  respectively.